# MySQL update table add different amount to each row

Tags: mysql, sql

### MySQL Table:

```
Key Total
 A   20
 B   15
 C   25
 D   30
```

### I have this data:

```
Key Total
 A   5
 C   10
 D   10
```

### I want to update the table:

by adding each row's total. Note the data is incomplete, so some rows (B) are not going to be updated. So the result should be:

```
Key Total
 A   25
 B   15
 C   35
 D   40
```

My current plan is running `update table set total = total + ? where key = ?`. But is there a more efficient way?

Comment: where's the second set of data stored? in a table?

Comment: ah, great, it is actually a hash map in a Java application, I imagine I had to write it as a table in a query if needed

Comment: If your hashmap is constant then yeah, store it in a permanent table, it'll be a lot more convenient. Other solution would be a ton of CASE WHEN... or a temp table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second set of data were stored in a table then it would have been much easier.

Let's say your first table is named as `first_table` and your second data set is stored a table named `second_table`.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE first_table AS FT
INNER JOIN second_table AS ST 
  ON FT.key = ST.key
SET FT.total = FT.total + ST.total;
```

---

[**SEE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/LHIOW98669)